# Can't obtain parameterless constructor of a struct

Tags: c#, reflection, struct

I'm trying to create an instance of a struct which's datatype is not known at compile time by obtaining and invoking it's parameterless constructor. The following (otherwise rather useless) code snippet shows what I do:

```
var i = new System.Int32();
var type = i.GetType();
var constructor = type.GetConstructor(System.Type.EmptyTypes);
var value = constructor.Invoke(null);
```

This doesn't work because `type.GetConstructor(System.Type.EmptyTypes)` returns `null`. When I step through this I can see that `type` *definitely is* `System.Int32` and as is evident from the first line there is a parameterless constructor. So why am I unable to obtain it?

I tried the same with an userdefined struct to rule out the posibility of restrictions in built in types but that shows the same behaviour.

Comment: Have you considered [`Activator.CreateInstance`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Activator.CreateInstance(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to invoke the parameterless constructor of a struct. Just use the activator for creation:

```
Activator.CreateInstance(i.GetType());
```

The reason you can't obtain a parameterless constructor of a struct is that it just does not exist.

Comment: Strictly speaking: a .net value-type *can* have a parameterless constructor - you  can't create one from C#, but you can in IL. Such constructors are ... well, you need to be very careful if you expect them to be used all the time, because there are lots of scenarios that don't invoke the constructor

Comment: @MarcGravell I know, but as far as i know this is a feature request for the next version of C#.

Answer (score 1):

The fact that the first line works doesn't mean there is a constructor. That is compiled either to the `initobj` instruction (which simply zeros the memory space), or even (depending on context, in the case of an `int` in particular) just to `ldc.i4.0`. No constructor is invoked there.